# Set initial state from props in constructor doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react.js typescript app, where I have a component (OrganizationsSearch) that receives its props from a parent component (Organizations), which in turn receives its props from redux.

In the OrganizationsSearch component, i initialize state like this:

```
export default class OrganizationsSearch extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            filteredOrganizations: this.props.organizations,
            filterQuery: ""
        }
    }
    ...
```

The problem is when i navigate to the component through my route setup, the `filteredOrganizations` state is not equal to `props.organizations`. `filteredOrganizations` is just an empty array.

As can be seen in the code above, i have a `filterQuery` state property. This property is attached to an input field. Whenever i change the input, a filter function is run that updates the state based on this property. When the function is triggered, the state is correctly updated to contain the organizations that match the query. If i delete the input field content so that it's equal to the initial state value, the filteredOrganizations state contain all of the organizations as it should also do initially on component load.

What do i have to do to set the initial state to be equal to the props?

Comment: You shouldn't set state with props in the constructor if you want the state to actively reflect updated props. Just use the props in your `render`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem could be that when the constructor of the OrganizationsSearch runs there is no data in this.props.organizations. You can easily check this with a console.log.

You could fix it that you only diplay the OrganizationsSearch component when the organization data is ready.You can display a Loading... text until then or some kind of progress indicator.

```js
render() {
...

  {organization ? <OrganizationsSearch organization={organization} /> : <div>Loading...</div>}

...
}
```

Another approach can be, that you do not store the filteredOrganization in the state. You can create it on the fly from organization and the filter value for the renderer. So there is only a single source of truth and you can avoid data inconsistencies. Storing prop data in state is discouraged anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be about your component lifecycle. 
The constructor is only called when the component is .. constructed. So depending on when redux sets your props, it might be too late, your component has already been "constructed" with an empty prop.
You can learn more in this kind of article https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-react-v16-4-new-component-lifecycle-methods-fa7b224efd7d

TL;DR you cant use the static function **getDerivedStateFromProps** for exemple :

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.value !== props.value) {
        return {
            derivedValue: deriveValueFromProps(props),
            mirroredProp: props.value
        }
    }
    // when null is returned no update is made to the state
    return null;
}
```